# Why does std::ofstream truncate without std::ios_base::trunc?

Tags: c++, ofstream

According to this C++ reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/, the default open mode for `std::ofstream` is `ios_base::out` and it mentions no implict other modes. Therefore I would expect that if I overwrite a large file with a small file, the "exceeding" part of the large file should stay untouched and only the first part of the file should be replaced by the new, shorter data.

On the other hand, the Apache C++ Standard Library User's Guide (http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/30-3.html) states in the note to paragraph 30.3.1.2: "For output file streams the open mode out is equivalent to out|trunc, that is, you can omit the trunc flag. For bidirectional file streams, however, trunc must always be explicitly specified."

I have tried this code:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream aFileStream("a.out", std::ios_base::out);
    aFileStream << "Hello world!";
    aFileStream.close();

    std::ofstream aFileStream2("a.out", std::ios::out);
    aFileStream2 << "Bye!";
    aFileStream2.close();
}
```

Both, with g++ 8.1 on Windows and g++ 6.3 on Linux, the Apache documentation seems to be right. The large file is truncated, nothing remains after writing the shorter string with the second file stream.

Why is it like that? Is cplusplus.com wrong? Or on what does the behaviour depent?

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) the out will delete content on already existing files (so overriding everything)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per [[ofstream.cons]/itemdecl:2](http://eel.is/c++draft/ofstream.cons#itemdecl:2):

> ```
> explicit basic_ofstream(const char* s,
>                         ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);
> ```

Therefore, the default mode for `ofstream` is `out`.  However, per [[tab:filebuf.open.modes]](http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf.members#tab:filebuf.open.modes), `out` and `out | trunc` both correspond to the stdio equivalent `"w"`, so they are equivalent.  Per [C11 7.21.5.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A695%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D):

> `w`: truncate to zero length or create text file for writing

Thus, it is correct to say that the default mode is `out`, and it is also correct to say that the default mode is equivalent to `out | trunc`.  This is guaranteed behavior.

On the other hand, per [[fstream.cons]/itemdecl:2](http://eel.is/c++draft/fstream.cons#itemdecl:2):

> ```
> explicit basic_fstream(
>   const char* s,
>   ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
> ```

Therefore, the default mode for `fstream` is `in | out`.  Per [[tab:filebuf.open.modes]](http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf.members#tab:filebuf.open.modes), `in | out` corresponds to `"r+"`, while `in | out | trunc` corresponds to `"w+"`, so they are not equivalent.  Per [C11 7.21.5.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A695%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D):

> `r+`: open text file for update (reading and writing) 
>   `w+`: truncate to zero length or create text file for update

Therefore, `fstream` does not truncate unless you specify `trunc`.
Note that if the desired file does not exist, `r+` will fail instead of creating the file.  In contrast, `w` and `w+` both create a new file in this case.

(See also: [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) on cppreference)

Comment: Great answer – Could you also link the quoted C standard? That would make the answer even better.

Comment: @FelixDombek Unfortunately, I am not aware of an official HTML C standard draft version.  The PDF version of the C11 final draft is available at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf.  Wait a sec ...

Comment: @FelixDombek Added link to standard and cppreference.

Comment: Thanks, awesome – Wait, how does your hash anchor name work?! It doesn't look at all like the standard given in https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: @FelixDombek Magic :) I use Firefox, and I right click on the navigation panel on the left, and choose "Copy link location", and there you go.

Comment: Another little comment: It might be worthwhile to point out that unlike an ofstream, an fstream with in|out will NOT create the file if it doesn't exist (but will instead fail.) So it's not a 1:1 replacement.

Comment: @FelixDombek Clarified.

Comment: Your answer has solved the problem which has been the actual reason for asking this question (a mixture of `fopen` and `std::ofstream`). Thank you! :-)